# What command should I use to change a file into the following format?

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I have an input file as following:

Oracle

Orac

Orac10

Sys

Sysadmin

abc

abca

bbbb

My Output should translate into the following:

Oracle,Orac,Orac10

Sys,Sysadmin

abc,abca

bbbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{key=substr($0,1,3)} key!=pkey{if (NR>1) print s; s=$0; pkey=key;next}
     {s=s "," $0} END{print s}' file
Oracle,Orac,Orac10
Sys,Sysadmin
abc,abca
bbbb
```

**Explanation:**

```
key=substr($0,1,3)    # extract first 3 chars of each line and store in variable key
key!=pkey {           # if previous key (pkey) is != current key then execute
  if (NR>1) print s   # for record>1 print aggregated string s
  s=$0                # reset s by storing current line in variable s
  pkey=key            # store current key in a variable pkey
  next                # move to next line
}                     # end of key!=pkey block
{s=s "," $0}          # append current line in var s after a comma
END{print s}          # print s last time
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thanks for the help. Could you just explain your steps a bit. I am new to unix shell scripting and I have use awk for basic translation.